# FT230X direct interfacing with 5V uC like PIC24FV &/ PIC18

Tags: usb, uart, ftdi

I am working on a project in which I am using PIC24FV32KA304. And I want to use FTDI FT230x usb to uart chip for communication with PC.

Datasheet of FTDI chip mentions that TTL input is 5V tolerant. So from this I understand that input to RX pin of FT230x can handle 5V.

My question is will it convert voltage level of TX to 5V? Can I directly interface RX, TX of FT230x with my 5V uC or do I need to use level converter?

Comment: PIC uart input pins are likely to be ttl thresholds, and work just fine, 16F628's are. Check the datasheet closely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level of the FT230x UART signals are determined by VCCIO which can be between 1.8V and 3.3V. Vih on the PIC is 0.8VDD so at 5V that would be 4V which would not be met by the FT230x. So you would need a level shifter to go between 3.3V and 5V, or use 3.3V to power the PIC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the FT230x in the bus-powered configuration you may need to be careful about backflow from the 3.3V rail into your 5V parts. Using a dedicated level-shifting isolator such as the ADUM1201 will take care of this, or a simple logic gate that is designed for partial power-down applications (meaning it has an Ioff parameter specified in the datasheet) such as putting a 74LVC1G34 on the FT230x TX pin.

In this case the 74LVC1G34 is powered with Vcc=5V and it will isolate the FT230x TX pin from the PIC until the 5V parts are powered up.

EDIT: @EE_socal brings up a good point. At 5V the 74LVC1G34 expects Vih to be 3.5V at minimum and the FT230X Voh is 2.97 worst-case. Something in the HCT series (e.g. 74HCT1G125) would be more appropriate but they have no provisions for managing backflow. Guess it depends on how the rest of your circuit is powered in the end.